Is it on-topic to ask for tips with learning?
I am currently trying to learn basic Italian from online resources (i.e. without a tutor). I have hit a stumbling block which I'm finding it very hard to overcome (struggling to remember the difference between Quanto/Quale/Quando and similar words in forming questions).
I cannot see any other questions of this type. Perhaps it's just a matter of hard rote learning but I'm hoping better speakers might be able to find some sort of rules or parallels I could cling to. Would such a question be off-topic?

Unfortunately we are somewhat lacking in good questions. All the more reasons to post yours!

@DenisNardin OK, have done :)

A question about a grammatical construction, which shows effort in trying to research the topic and is not solely driven by the willingness to get a quick translation, is always on-topic!
I'd encourage you to post that question. Also, you'd see there are similar ones (as in, in the same fashion) already. 

One of the functions of an SE language site (I'm on several) is to correct grammatical errors/lapses made by "newbies." So if you post a self-worked "erroneous" construction or translation, and ask for comment, the question will probably be answered.
What SE sites will not do is to translate "from scratch." The idea is that the questioner must demonstrate a level of effort in learning comparable to others' efforts in answering.
